# Insert to database and viewing of records in one single page in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, oracle-sqldeveloper

I already have a page displaying the records in database with pagination and search function. I got the tutorial from here: [Sorting, Filtering, and Paging with the Entity Framework in an ASP.NET MVC Application](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application). However, I'm having trouble when implementing record insert. So here's the overview of my process, please let me know if I'm wrong since I'm still in the process of learning MVC:

**ProjectModel.edmx** - my generated database model

**UserModel.cs** - contains the columns from the database and some other variables that will hold the value depending on the row result in database (ex: I have a `user_status` variable that will display "Active" if Inactive_Date of a record is null and "Inactive" if Inactive_Date of a record has a value)

**UserViewModel.cs** - It contains the `public IPagedList<Project.Models.UserModel> Users` and the varaiables to be used for textboxes in the `View`. I created an object of `IPagedList<Project.Models.UserModel>` bec. this will be returned by the controller and needed by the Model for looping the records in database.

```
public class UserModel
{
    public string user_id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "User")]
    public string user_desc { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Status")]
    public string user_status { get; set; }
}
public class UserViewModel
{
    public IPagedList<Project.Models.UserModel> Users { set; get; }
    public string userId { get; set; }
    public string userDesc { get; set; }
}
```

**UserController.cs** - The pagination is processed here. I have a LINQ that selects the records from `ProjectEntities _odb`'s `USR_MSTR` table and puts it in `UserModel`'s variables. I put it in the `UserViewModel`'s `Users` So this can be for-loop'ed in the `View.

```
public ActionResult Create(string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page)
{
    if (searchString != null)
    {
        page = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        searchString = currentFilter;
    }

    ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;
    ViewBag.UserFilter = GetSelectListItems();  
    int pageSize = 10;
    int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);

    var users = from ug in _odb.USR_MSTR
                     select new UserModel
                     {
                         user_id = ug.USR_ID,
                         user_desc = ug.USR_DESC,
                         user_status = (ug.INACTV_DT == null ? "Active" : "Inactive")
                     };

    var vm = new UserViewModel();
    vm.Users = users.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);

    return View(vm);
}

public JsonResult Save_User(UserViewModel model)
{
    string _message = string.Empty;
    using (var _odb = new ProjectEntities())
    {
        try
        {
            USR_MSTR usr_master = new USR_MSTR();
            usr_master.USER_ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Remove(20);
            usr_master.USER_DESC = model.userDesc;
            usr_master.CREATE_DT = DateTime.Now;

            _odb.USR_MSTR.Add(usr_master);
            _odb.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _message = ex.InnerException.Message;
        }
    }
    return Json(true);
}
```

**Create.cshtml** (under User folder in View) - So I assume now that the `Model`'s purpose is to list the records from the database, while the `ViewModel` is to where I'll use strongly-typed textboxes (ex: m => m.userDesc) and get the value of the textbox by calling the **SaveUser** javascript in `Submit` button

```
@model Project.Models.UserViewModel
@using PagedList.Mvc;
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create User";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "User", FormMethod.Get))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="container">
        <div class="container">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.userDesc)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.userDesc)
            @Html.Label("Status")
            Active @Html.RadioButton("Status", "Active", new { @id = "rActive" })
            Inactive @Html.RadioButton("Status", "Inactive", new { @id = "rInactive" })
        </div>
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <div class="pull-right">
            <input type="submit" id="btnSave" value="Save" class="btn btn-success" onclick="return SaveUser();"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-control">
            <div class="pull-right" style="margin-right:-127px">
                @Html.Label("Filter")
                @Html.DropDownList("UserFilter")
                @Html.TextBox("SearchString", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string)
                <button class="btn btn-default-search" type="submit" />
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <table class="table table-scroll table-hover table-striped bootgrid-table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="hidden">
                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.user_id)
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                @Html.ActionLink("USER", "Create", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.UserSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                @Html.ActionLink("STATUS", "Create", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.StatusSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach (var item in Model.Users)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td id="userId" class="hidden">
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.user_id)
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.user_desc)
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.user_status)
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                Page @(Model.Users.PageCount < Model.Users.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.Users.PageNumber) of @Model.Users.PageCount

                @Html.PagedListPager(Model.Users, page => Url.Action("Create",
                new { page, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }))
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

**SaveUser.js** - I'm not quite clear about this since this is being used by my colleague and is working, but not for me with pagination. He didn't have yet the function that display records in database (I'm the one in charge in developing codes for displaying records with pagination and he's doing the database inserts). I think it's function is to go to the JsonResult function in my controller to execute the record insert.

```
function SaveUser() {
    debugger;
    var json = {
        userId: $('#userId').val(),
        userDesc: $('#userDesc').val()
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: '/User/Save_User',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify(json),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        , success: function () {
            alert("User was successfully saved.");
            window.location.href = "Create";
        }
    });

};
```

As I've said, my colleague's save function does not work with my code above. Where I'm having problem in is when the `Save_User` JsonResult is triggered by the `onclick` in Submit button, I'm generating this error:

> An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in
>   Project.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.

Could someone check if I'm getting the MVC right? And what makes the program generate the error?

Comment: Unclear what you wanting to do here. Your button is a submit button but you do not cancel the default submit in the `SaveUser()` function (you making a call to both `Create()` and `Save_User()`. But why in the world are your using `window.location.href = "Create";` - the whle point of ajax is to stay on the same page, not refresh the whole page.

Comment: Oooh, thanks ekad! Shouldn't have just copied that js. I'm whole to the web development and still learning a lot from asp, javascript and mvc. Do you think I'm also wrong with the SaveUser js using 'POST' as type when my FormMethod in view is GET? And also, I'm still finding how that NullReferenceException is occuring

Comment: Which line of code throws the error? There are a few odd things in your code - e.g `userId: $('#userId').val(),` - where is the element with `id="userId"`, but in any case you do not even use it.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that too. It's not being used yet. As of now, I'm just leaving it there. The error shows up in `JsonResult Save_User`, when it's in `_odb.SaveChanges();`. The `ProjectEntities` was instantiated. checking the parameter `UserViewModel model`, the values were passed just fine too. It's property, `model.userDesc`, retrieved the value from the View's textbox